# What are the arguments against modals when a page loads?

Tags: e-commerce, popup, signup-signon, modal-windows

I'm working for an e-commerce client who has requested a design for a newsletter signup modal to appear on page load the second time a user visits the site. I've tried to explain to them that blocking a users progress with a popup wall which forces them to click is bad UX, that modals should be triggered by a user action and not just by arriving somewhere and that there are ways to display this sign up that won't annoy users.

Are there more concrete figures/studies I can point to that help make avoiding this a bit more straight forward? They heard it "isn't so bad" from an "ECRM industry expert" and I'm pretty sure ECRM will beat poor old UX unless I get some support.

Answer (score 2):

Jakob Nielsen warns about using automatic popups (even though old javascript popups aren't technically the same thing as modal windows, they have the same basic function) - http://www.nngroup.com/articles/most-hated-advertising-techniques/.

These surveys are based on ads and not regular site content, but I think that there's a big chans that the users will see anything that pops up as something annoying (ads etc.) and just click it away.

[This is another thread](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/31335/are-mailing-list-popups-bad-usability) discussing a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a common misconception that different apps should have different UX.
I contend that what is good for ECRM is also good for a supply chain application.
Ask them if they would like different UX design in Work versus Excel.

Find some standard guideline to support that UX design.
I personally don't like modal.
I found this in some Microsoft UX guidelines.
[USguide.pdf](http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/1/9/e191fd8c-bce8-4dba-a9d5-2d4e3f3ec1d3/ux%20guide.pdf)

> Ask questions carefully Avoid asking unessential questions using modal
>   dialogs—prefer modeless alternatives. Better yet, the current context
>   can reveal the user's intent, often eliminating the need to ask at
>   all. If you must ask a question in your UI, express it in terms of
>   users' goals and tasks, not in terms of technology. Provide options
>   that users understand (again, phrased in terms of goals and tasks, not
>   technology) and clearly differentiate. Make sure to provide enough
>   information for users to make informed decisions.

I personally don't think industry experts should be designing the UI.  They have expertise in in the field and not UX.  I get so frustrated when I ask for a function requirement and get back a screen design.